# Changin URL display text in citation

Tags: hyperref, citing, urls

I am using `hyperref` package which automatically loads `url` package for me and using them to give citation in a document.

The standard use of `cite+url` is, in my understanding, `\cite{cite_key} REFERENCE, \url{www.example.com}`.

This will display the URL text as `www.example.com`. I would like to know how to change the displayed text to something like used on stackexchange to provide links : [dont_click_fake_link](https://www.example.com/)

It seems like a really trivial question but I wasn't able to find any answers online. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: @Mico Yes actually, I meant the `url` pacakge. Thank you. Also, the answer below did the job for me.

Comment: The [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/) package does **not** load the [cite](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cite/) package.

Comment: Yes. Again a typo. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `\href`

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue}
\begin{document}
Something to click \href{https://stackexchange.com/}{\texttt{visit\_stack\_exchange}}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will only be able to accept as answer after a few seconds. Also, could you please confirm that this is not possible to do with `url`?

Comment: If the printed text should look like a URL, for example because it is part of a URL, `\nolinkurl` may come in handy: `\href{https://stackexchange.com/}{\nolinkurl{visit_stack_exchange}}`.